# SSH screen: how to back to the original window after Ctrl+a+c?

Tags: ssh

I'm running codes in session `run`. When I'm at this session, I occasionally create a new window by `Ctrl-a c` (in fact, I want to use `Ctrl-a d` to detach this session). Then I use `Ctrl-a d` to detach the session. But when I tried to enter the session `run` again to check the running progress using `screen -r run`, I found that I couldn't enter the initial session which runs my codes, instead, entered the created new window in which nothing runs. The `screen -ls` shows only one session named `run`. But `top` shows that all commands are still running. How can I enter the initial session `run` which runs my codes?

Comment: it's not clear what is the exact scenario you are trying to describe, but maybe

`screen -x `

Comment: @oryades I have edited my question to try to make it more clear. `screen -x run` can't work.

Comment: so as I understand, you create a screen session by `screen -S run`, then detach from that session, later on, when you run `screen -r run` you don't see the initial session? Actually `screen -r run` will not create new session with name run, but only will connect to the existing session.

Comment: @oryades sorry for the confusion caused. I'm at the session `run` and want to detach it using `Ctrl+a d`, but occasionally, pressed `Ctrl+a c`, which creates a new window. Then detach the session and want to attach again the session running my codes using `screen -r run` . The problem is that I can't attach the initial session, but instead, the created new window. `screen -ls` shows only one session named `run`. How can I attach the initial session?

Comment: It seems that the initial session is covered by the new window created by `Ctrl+a c`, thus the `screen -r run` only attached the new window, not initial session.

Comment: so `Ctrl+a a` should switch the windows in the given session

Comment: @oryades Great! This is what I want. Thanks.